# How can I get elements of a certain name from an XML document as an XML String? (with XDocument)

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How can I get elements of a certain name from an XML document as an XML String? (with XDocument)

I.e, say I have this:

```
<root>
    <orange id="orange1"></orange>
    <orange id="orange2"></orange>
    <orange id="orange3"></orange>

    <apple id="apple1"></apple>
    <apple id="apple2"></apple>
    <apple id="apple3"></apple>
</root>
```

How can I get only the XML for the apples? Ie the XML string for those three lines?

My current code is:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(xmlFilePath))
{
    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(reader);
    string items = xmlDocument.Descendants("apple").ToString();
}
```

...but in this example, `items` ends up as: `System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetDescendants>d__a`  rather than the XML string. I can't seem to find any method which will give me back the XML for the matched elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `ToString()` on the result of calling `Descendants()`. It's not really clear what you expected that to do, but you *are* getting the elements correctly. For example:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(xmlFilePath))
{
    // Any reason for not using XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath)?
    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(reader);
    var items = xmlDocument.Descendants("apple");
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("id").Value); // Or whatever
    }
}
```

If you want to concatenate the results of converting each `XElement` to string, you could use:

```
var items = string.Join("", xmlDocument.Descendants("apple"));
```

or

```
var items = string.Concat(xmlDocument.Descendants("apple"));
```

Comment: You was right, don't read the question correctly. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: I'm trying to merge two XML files (a template and a different xml file with some data items). I don't need any access to the actual values and I don't want to work with objects as "in real life" the XML is dramatically more complex than my example shows (eg the "apple" elements are a deep tree structure).

Comment: @NickG: What do you mean by "I don't want to work with objects"? Your code is likely to be *much* cleaner if you deal with `XElement` objects than strings...

Comment: I know it seems wrong, but in this particular case my program doesn't care about the data in the files at all (it's just a pre-processor) - it literally just needs them to be merged together with all the XML inside any tag called 'apples' replacing a placeholder tag in the separate file. All the real work on the XML is done in a different application and that deserializes them into objects.

Comment: So your second code block is exactly what I need - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Concat(xmlDocument.Descendants("apple"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ToString()` on a collection of xml elements, hence your results. If I'm reading your requirements correctly, you need something like:

```
var items = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                        xmlDocument.Descendants("apple")
                                   .Select(e => e.ToString()));
```